# Scanf and format changer

Tags: c, input, user-input

`scanf` is a function which takes user inputs. But according to the code in the picture the compiler understands 34 as the value for "y", but it is only the neglected input of x, so can anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question, rather than posting links to it (even worse, links to *images* of it).

Comment: (Include the input, too (making it a quote): are you trying to enter a 4-digit x-value?))

Comment: Sorry to say, some people know only to put on hold or to delete. Try to help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning for the `%2d` directive stops when the two digits `12` have been read. That leaves "3" as the next character in the input stream.

Then the space character in the format string says to skip white space characters (spaces, tabs, and so on), if there are any. There are not, so “3” remains the next character in the input stream.

Then the `%d` specifier causes a decimal integer to be read, so 34 is assigned to `y`.

If you wish to skip the digits remaining after `x` is scanned, you can use `%*[0-9]` to scan and ignore digits until a non-digit is seen., as in `%2d%*[0-9] %d %*f %5s`.

Comment: Thanks Eric Postpischil